# Redis with twemproxy ZRANGE comand

Tags: redis

I'm looking for a way to have redis sharded and add redundancy. Found https://github.com/twitter/twemproxy which seems to have the sharding aspect covered as well some of redundancy but I'm just wondering if anybody used it and worked well with http://redis.io/commands/ZRANGE.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what makes you troublous. As I know, no matter with twemproxy or redis cluster, redis shards with keys.
If you use redis above 3,change twemproxy to cluster unless you are familiar with twemproxy, even though it is mature.

Maybe you should have a look at 
http://redis.io/topics/partitioning.

Comment: I use sets - my concern is with the fact that a set is mapped from a key which will be present only on one server with twemproxy ... unless I'm missing something, I think with the redis cluster will replicate the keys among servers.